# Delete line if line matches "foo", line above matches "bar" and line below matches "baz"?

Tags: awk, sed

Using sed and/or awk, I'd like to be able to delete a line only if it contains the string "foo" AND the lines before and after contain the strings "bar" and "baz" respectively.

So for this input:

```
blah
blah
foo
blah
bar
foo
baz
blah
```

we would delete the second foo but nothing else, leaving:

```
blah
blah
foo
blah
bar
baz
blah
```

I've tried using a while loop to read the file line by line, but this is slow and I can't work out how to match the previous and next lines.

Edit - as requested in a comment, this is the current state of my while loop. Currently only matches the previous line (stored from the previous loop as $linepre).

```
linepre=0 
while read line
do 
   if [ $line != foo ] && [ $linepre != bar ]
   then 
       echo $line
   fi
linepre=$line
done < foobarbaz.txt
```

Pretty ugly.

Comment: `tried using a while loop to read the file line by line` please add that code to question.. :)

Comment: Good point @Sundeep, have edited. It's pretty ugly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an elegant **`perl`** solution see [Sundeep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49113801/8344060).

For a similar and very nice **`sed`** solution see [potong's second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49128926/8344060)

Both solutions read the file completely into memory and process it in one go. This is fine if you don't need to process GB file sizes. In other words, these are the **best** solutions (if we ignore `CASE3`).

***comment:*** both solutions fail `CASE3` (see below). `CASE3` is an exceptional debatable case.

---

**Update 1:** the following `awk` solution is a new script which works in all cases. Earlier solutions, for which this answer got accepted failed on particular cases. The presented solution solves the *nested* grouping (`CASE3` below):

```
awk 'BEGIN{p=1;l1=l2=""}
     (NR>2) && p {print l1}
     { p=!(l1~/bar/&&l2~/foo/&&/baz/);
       l1=l2;l2=$0
     }
     END{if (l1!="" && p) print l1
         if (l2!=""     ) print l2}' <file>
```

To solve the problem, we constantly buffer 3 lines stored in `l1`, `l2` and `$0`. Each processing of a new line, we determine if `l1` should be printed or not in the next cycle and swap the buffered lines. The printing starts only from `NR=3` onward. The condition to print is if `l1` contains `bar`, `l2` contains `foo` and `$0` contains `baz`, then we do not print in the next cycle.

**Update 2:** A `sed` solution based on the same principle can be obtained. `sed` has two memories. The *pattern space* is where you do all operations on and the *hold space* is a long term memory. The idea is to put the word `print` in the *hold space*, but we can only do this by swapping the spaces around (using `x`)

```
 sed '1{x;s/^.*$/print/;x;N};                           #1
      N;                                                #2
      x;/print/{z;x;P;x};x;                             #3
      /bar.*\n.*foo.*\n.*baz/!{x;s/^.*$/print/;x};      #4
      $s/\(bar.*\)\n.*foo.*\n\(.*baz\)/\1\n\2/;         #5
      D' <file>                                         #6
```

- line `#1` initializes the state by placing the word `print` in the hold space (`x;s...;x`)and append another line to the pattern space (`N`)
- line `#2` adds the third line to the pattern space
- line `#3` determines if we need to print the first line of the pattern space by checking the hold space and delete the hold space `P` prints upto the first `\n` in the pattern space and `z` zaps the pattern space
- line `#4` determines if we should print in the next cycle. checks if the real pattern matches, if not put the word `print` in the hold space
- line `#5`, is the end-of-file condition
- line `#6` deletes upto the first `\n` in the pattern space and goes back to `#1` without reading a new line.

At exit, the pattern-space is printed again.

*comment*: if you want to see how the pattern space and hold space look like, you can add after each line the following code: `s/^/P:/;l;s/^P://;x;s/^/H:/;l;s/^H://;x`. This line will print both spaces with `P:` respectively `H:` in front.

**Used test file:**

```
# bar-foo-baz test file
# An asterisk indicates the foo
# lines that should be removed
<CASE0 :: default case>
bar
foo (*)
baz
<CASE1 :: reset cycle on second line>
bar
foobar
foo (*)
baz
<CASE2 :: start cycle at end of previous cycle>
bar
foo (*)
bazbar
foo (*)
baz
<CASE3 :: nested cases>
bar
foobar (*)
foobaz (*)
baz
<CASE4 :: end-of-file case>
bar
foo
```

**Formerly accepted answer:** (updated to indicate which cases fail)

**`awk`: *fails `CASE3`***

```
awk '!/baz/&&(c==2){print foo}
     /bar/         {c=1;print;next}
     /foo/ &&(c==1){c++;foo=$0;next}
                   {c=0;print}
     END{if(c==2){print foo}}' <file>
```

This solution prints all lines by default, except if the line contains `foo` which comes after a line containing `bar`. The logic above just decides if we should print the line `foo` or not.

- `!/baz/&&(c==2){print foo}` : this solves early termination. If no `baz` is found after a valid `bar-foo`combination, it prints the `foo`line.
- `/bar/{c=1;print;next}` : this initialises the start of a new cycle. If `bar` is found, set `c` to `1`, print the line and move to the next line. `bar`lines are always printed. This line resolves `CASE1` and `CASE2`.
- `/foo/&&(c==1){c++;foo=$0;next}` : this checks the `bar-foo`combination. It stores the the `foo`line and moves to the next line.
- `{c=0;print}`, if we reached this point, it implies that we did not find a `bar`line or a `bar-foo`combination. Just print the line by default and reset the counter to zero.
- `END{if(c==2){print foo}}` this statement just solves `CASE4`

**`gawk`: *fails `CASE3`***

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS="";RS="bar[^\n]*\n[^\n]*foo[^\n]*\n[^\n]*baz"}
     {sub(/\n[^\n]*foo[^\n]*\n/,"\n",RT); print $0 RT}' <file>
```

The `RS` is set to `bar[^\n]*\n[^\n]*foo[^\n]*\n[^\n]*baz`, i.e. the pattern we are interested in. Here, `[^\n]*\n[^\n]*` represents a string containing a single `\n`, thus the `RS` represents valid `bar-foo-baz` combination. The found record separator `RT` is edited with `sub` to remove the `foo`line and printed after the found record.

> **`RT` (gawk extension)** The input text that matched the text denoted by
>   `RS`, the record separator. It is set every time a record is read.

**`sed`: *fails `CASE1, CASE2, CASE3, CASE4`***

```
sed -n '/bar/{N;/\n.*foo/{N;/foo.*\n.*baz[^\n]*$/{s/\n.*foo.*\n/\n/}}};p' <file>
```

- `/bar/{N;...}` if the line contains `bar`, append the next line to the *pattern buffer* (`N`)
- `/\n.*foo/{N;...}` if the *pattern buffer* has `foo` after a newline character, append the next line to the *pattern buffer* (`N`)
- `/foo.*\n.*baz[^\n]*$/{s/\n.*foo.*\n/\n/}` if the *pattern buffer* contains `foo` followed by a single newline and ends with a line containing `baz`, remove the line containing `foo`. The search pattern here excludes cases as `barfoo\nfoobaz\ncar`

Comment: good one :) would suggest to add explanation for first answer as well :)

Comment: @Sundeep as requested, comments added and another `sed` solution.

Comment: What happens when `bar` then `foo` is followed by `bar` ,`foo` then `baz`?

Comment: @kvantour no, sed and 1st awk solution doesn't work.. the gawk one does...

Comment: @Sundeep you were correct there were problems. I have updated the answer with 2 new solutions and much more tests. Afaik, all cases work now.

Answer (score 3):

Modified sample for more exotic cases:

```
$ cat ip.txt 
blah
bar
blah
foo
blah
bar
foo
baz
blah
bar
foobar
foo
baz
asdf
```

if `perl` is okay and input file is small enough to fit memory requirements

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/bar.*\n\K.*foo.*\n(?=.*baz)//g' ip.txt
blah
bar
blah
foo
blah
bar
baz
blah
bar
foobar
baz
asdf
```

- `-0777` to slurp entire input file
- `bar.*\n\K` check if previous line contains `bar`
- `.*foo.*\n` current line contains `foo`
- `(?=.*baz)` next line contains `baz`
- See **lookarounds** section in [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) for more details on this regex. Here they ensure that overlapping matches across 3 lines are taken care

Comment: `perl` for the win! very nice!

Comment: Wow - the Perl solution is so elegant! I'm definitely going to try and use Perl for these kind of things in the future.

Comment: @Sundeep, there is a nested situation `bar \n foobar \n foobaz \n baz` which seems to fail. I would expect the two `foo`lines to be removed. It is however an exceptional case.

Comment: @kvantour yeah, because `bar \n foobar \n foobaz` would result in regex engine moving to `foobaz` after removing `foobar` line... so, it won't be able to match the `bar` that was already removed.. not sure if regex can handle such cases :)

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/bar/!b;n;/foo/!ba;N;s/^.*\n\(.*baz\)/\1/;t;P;D' file
```

If the current line does not contain `bar` print it and begin a new cycle. Otherwise print the line containing `bar` and read the next line into the pattern space. If that line does not contain `foo` go back and check that it does not contain `bar`. Otherwise, append the next line to the current line (containing `foo`) and check if the appended line contains `baz`. If it does remove the first line containing `foo` and then print the line containing `baz` and begin a new cycle. Otherwise, the appended line does not contain `baz` so print the line containing `foo` and delete it and then check if the appended line contains `bar`.

An alternative, slurping the whole file into memory:

```
sed -zr 's/(bar[^\n]*)\n[^\n]*foo[^\n]*(\n[^\n]*baz)/\1\2/g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

***Solution 1st:*** For same identical file(which you shown) without any further conditions following may help you on same then.

```
awk '/^bar/ && getline var ~ /^foo/ && getline var1 ~ /^baz/{print "bar" ORS "baz";next} 1'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/bar/{val=FNR} /^foo/ && ++val==FNR{value=$0;getline;if($0 ~ /^baz/){print value ORS $0;val="";next} else {print value}} 1'    Input_file
```

Different permutations and combinations checks on above 2nd code:

***Situation 1st:*** When string `bar` string `foo` and string `baz` comes then it will work fine.

***Situation 2nd:*** When string `bar` comes and then string `baz` comes without `foo` then also it should work.

Comment: nope, this won't work... try with a line `bar` followed by line not containing `foo`

Comment: nope, using getline would lead you to trouble here... check with line `bar` followed by `foobar` , `foo`, `baz`...

Comment: @Sundeep, like this we can create n number of combinations :) let OP say this and I could fix it then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 your first answer worked well for me, but the edited version doesn't appear to delete the second foo?

Comment: @birac, please check my edited post with explanation on it too.

Answer (score 0):

#### First variant - using sed

```
sed -r ':l; N; $!bl; s/(^|\nbar\n)foo\n(baz$|\n)/\1\2/g' input.txt
```

or, the same, but shorter and probably faster, by using the `-z` option:

```
sed -zr 's/(^|\nbar\n)foo\n(baz\n|$)/\1\2/g' input.txt
```

**-z** = separate lines by NUL characters. This option can be used for putting all text into the memory (if the text doesn't have NUL characters).

#### Second variant - using grep and sed

```
grep --color=always -Pz '\^|\nbar\n\Kfoo\n(?=baz\n)' input.txt | sed '/31m/d'
```

Both variants put all text in the memory before processing, so for large files they are not optimal.

**Input**

```
blah
blah
foo
blah
bar
foo
baz
blah
```

**Output**

```
blah
blah
foo
blah
bar
baz
blah
```